# multiple projects maven builds

Tags: maven

I have foundation-project, which is independent of all projects and then proj-A, proj-B which will depend on foundation-project.

I would like to have foundation-project build triggered when proj-A or proj-B build triggered.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you like that than the projects are not independent anymore...this is called an mutli module build...

Comment: multi module is having a project with multiple modules inside it. foundation-project will not be part of proj-A, proj-B structure.